# Assign seats in an Auditorium

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I encountered an Interview Question:

There is an event in the auditorium and Given capacity of the auditorium is NxM.
Every group of person booked ticket and all the tickets are booked, Now you have to assign seat number to all of them such that minimum number of group split.

So basically a 2-D array is given and we have some groups of certain size(different groups may be of different size).Array needs to be completely filled with minimum number of groups split.

One Brute force Recursive approach I found is :Place first group ,then second group and so on.Permute this arrangement to find the arrangement with minimum split.

One efficient solution I found was using subset sum problem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

I could not understand how subset sum problem can be used to solve this problem.
Please suggest how can I approach this problem.I am not looking for code,just psuedo-code or algorithm will suffice.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem Found this from the link you provided. It looks pretty closely related

Comment: You say you've found an efficient solution using subset sum, but then you ask for how you can approach the problem. Why doesn't the solution you've already found answer your question?

Comment: I Found one forum on which some one commented it can be solved using subset sum.But I did not undesrtandd how it can be solved using subset sum problem

Comment: Is your question how to solve this problem, or to explain how to solve the problem using subset sum?

Comment: I asked for both.How it can be solved using subset sum and is there any other better way of solving this ?

Comment: It would be odd if it could be efficiently solved using subset-sum since that problem is NP-Complete?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm assuming that "group-split" means that some part of the group is in one row and remaining is in another. If the number of seats in a row are N, and given a set which contains the size of the different groups, you need to find a subset that will sum to N. If such a subset is found, that row will be filled without breaking any groups. If there is no such subset found, then you will need to break at least 1 group. Then there can be multiple strategies here.

1) You can pick a group that will be split across 2 rows. This group can be the largest of the remaining, or the smallest or can be picked at random. Once this group is decided, you have 2 rows with less than N empty seats that need to be filled recursively.

2) The strategy can be to find a subset that sums to 2*N - if found, 1 group will be split. If not found, then find a subset that sums to 3*N with 2 group-splits and so on. The maximum number of group-splits will be M-1 for M rows.

Continue 1) or 2) to fill M number of rows in the theatre.